# How do I sort nested string elements

Tags: python-3.x

I want to reorder pairs of elements that should then be reordered as triples and finally the triples re-ordered.

For example - I want the following (I know this won't work but don't know how to write it):

```
old_x = [(('ABC', '123'), ('XYZ', 'ABC'), ('XYZ', '123')),(('ABC', '123'), ('DEF', 'ABC'), ('DEF', '123'))]
new_x = sort(old_x)
```

to be re-ordered as :

```
new_x = [(('123', 'ABC'), ('123', 'DEF'), ('ABC', 'DEF')),(('123', 'ABC'), ('123', 'XYZ'), ('ABC', 'XYZ'))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your new sorted list you have to first reverse tuples inside sublists, sort the sublists, and the sort the whole list:

```
old_x = [(('ABC', '123'), ('XYZ', 'ABC'), ('XYZ', '123')),(('ABC', '123'), ('DEF', 'ABC'), ('DEF', '123'))]

new_x = sorted([sorted(tuple(val[::-1] for val in subl)) for subl in old_x])

print(new_x)
```

Prints:

```
[[('123', 'ABC'), ('123', 'DEF'), ('ABC', 'DEF')], [('123', 'ABC'), ('123', 'XYZ'), ('ABC', 'XYZ')]]
```